# Arranging R drop down menus in R Shiny side by side (or in a grid)

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

Given the MWE below, how do I arrange the drop-down menus side by side, or if I have a lot of them - say 10 - how could I arrange them in a 5x2 grid or something?

I am terrible at Shiny UI - any help much appreciated...

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMobile)

# define UI elements
ui <- f7Page(

  f7SingleLayout(
    navbar = f7Navbar(
    ),
    f7Card(selectInput(inputId = "initial_choice",
                       label = "First choice:",
                       choices = c("Choice 1", "Choice 2", "Choice 3")) , #first drop down
           selectInput(inputId = "second_choice",
                       label = "Second choice:",
                       choices = c("Choice 1", "Choice 2", "Choice 3")) # second drop down to put by its side 
    )
  )


)

# server calculations
server <- function(input, output) {

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```